# How to write unit test for angularjs Attribute type directives in jasmine

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have some directives without using any template/templateUrl. How can i write a unit test for this directive. The below code is my directive.

```
var app = angular.module('SampleDirective');

app.directive('sampleContent', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {

            content: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var eventHandlers = [];

            function onContentChanged(value) {
                if (value) {
                    element.html('');
                    element.append(value);
                }
            }

            function onDestroy() {
                angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function (callback) {
                    callback();
                });

                element.remove();
            }

            eventHandlers.push(scope.$watch('content', onContentChanged));
            eventHandlers.push(scope.$on("$destroy", onDestroy));
        }
    };
}]);
```

can anyone suggest me how to write a unit test for this sample..

Answer (score 0):

I have written unit test for the above code.. Is it correct one??

```
describe("sampleContent", () => {

        let scope;
        let compile;
        let element;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module("SampleDirective"));

        beforeEach(() => {
            inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
                scope = $rootScope;
                compile = $compile("<input sample-content=\"ContentValue\"></input>");
                element = compile(scope);
            });

        });
        describe("onContentChanged", () => {
            it("should validate onContentChanged when the value is a valid content", () => {

                scope.$$childHead.content = "This is a sampleContent";
                scope.$digest();
                expect(element[0].textContent).toEqual("This is a sampleContent");
            });
            it("should validate onContentChanged when the value is not a valid content", () => {

                scope.$$childHead.content = undefined;
                scope.$digest();
                expect(element[0].textContent).toEqual("");
            });
        });

    });
```